# port vertex AI dashbrd to jupyter notebook - how create tf.dataset from jsonl exported from dashboard

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tf.keras, google-cloud-vertex-ai

using Vertex AI dashboard on a model with labeled image dataset went fine.

Exported the dataset from dashboard to jsonl with a gs URI in a bucket

from Github samples i have a sample using a std platform Dataset for image labeling and i just want to change the code to load from my gs URI for the jsonl export of MY image dataset.

Jupyter notebook DS related code i need to change:

[image]

(see below ) my exported jsonl data for training  (format sample )

```
{"imageGcsUri":"gs://test_yayatv/gcs3/Screenshot 2023-02-07 1.54.08 PM.png","classificationAnnotation":{"displayName":"mural","annotationResourceLabels":{"aiplatform.googleapis.com/annotation_set_name":"8066716590760001536"}},"dataItemResourceLabels":{}}
```

my question - how to consume the export above in the context of a jupyter notebook training sample set up to train on labeled image dataset like the export above ???

training dataset linked above ( after export )

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

among the [git samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/pipelines/google_cloud_pipeline_components_automl_images.ipynb) for Jupyter notebooks , i found a sample pipeline allowing for a simple 2-line rev to swap in my dataset created using the Vertex dashboard tag for *Datasets*.

Under Datasets, using the dashboard for dataset.export() , i was able to get 2 required GS urls to be plugged back into the notebook sample for a pipeline to train/ deploy model for image classification.

DS input :

```
gs://cloud-ai-platform-2ebb9454-f94d-4a1a-bab0-ff085e71e2c1/data/export-data-garbage_labels_t-2023-02-16T16:21:11.409490Z/image_classification_single_label/garbage_labels_t_icn-8066716590760001536/data-00001-of-00001.jsonl
```

is the json-lines file defining all my training/test photos and the label value corresponding to each photo. This file (jsonl) was output by the *export* operation in the vertex dashboard tag for datasets.

```
gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/dataset/ioformat/image_classification_single_label_io_format_1.0.0.yaml
```

is the schema def for the json-lines file mentioned above

Using the link at top for git samples and using the jupyter notebook interface ( Vertex AI dashbrd ) on a specific pipeline for image classification, i  manually run notebook steps 1 - 19 from sample opened in dashboard using tools for github and the samples project there.

in the input step 19 i edited my 2 lines in for a different dataset ( my photos, my labels ) before compiling and running the pipeline job.

see my inputs
[image]

pipeline code before change to input parm values:
ImageDatasetCreateOp.gcs_source ,
import_schema_uri

[image]

relevant pipeline API docs below
[image]

It took alot of reading to make sense of all the potential avenues to solve my issue. Key insights were that the KF pipeline samples exposed the API for dataset input in a way that would allow just 2 line changes allowing me to redifine the Vertex/pipeline input dataset.