# How to read images stored in GCS Bucket from Vertex AI Workbench - Jupyter notebook for image processing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, computer-vision, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I trying deep learning image processing with keras and opencv on vertex ai, I want to read my images dataset stored on google cloud storage bucket, but I'm unable to read it. When I'm specifying the gcs uri path, it is trying to search this folder in vertex ai notebook's vm.

What is the possible solution for reading images from gcs in vertex ai workbench notebook?

Comment: Can you share a piece of code where you search in GCS and the result that you get?

Comment: Code : `import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img

# load the image
img = load_img("gs://ml-sample/images_data/images/WORK_ORDER_001.jpg")

print(type(img))
print(img.format)
print(img.mode)
print(img.size)

# show the image
img.show()`                 So basically here I'm specifying the gcs bucket path, I'm able to read image stored on notebook's VM but I want to directly read from bucket without loading into vm's local storage, here I'm getting error `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Are you sure about your path?

Comment: similar scenario in link ( how to adjust samples from existing Dataset to *my* dataset ). in general i looked through various samples finding that *pipeline* for images seemed to allow me to just change 2 lines for DS input ( my gs:// uri ,  schema uri that i needed for a DS which i had EXPORTED in Vertex AI dashboard. Export leaves u with property values which u can plug back in to sample code using a Jupyter notebook cell and the update facility for those cells. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75477080/port-vertex-ai-dashbrd-to-jupyter-notebook-how-create-tf-dataset-from-jsonl-ex